# Restricting access to some lines in JTextArea?

Tags: java, text, jtextarea

I wanted to make a JTextArea where the user can't erase the previous line. Just like the Command Prompt in Windows and the terminal in Linux, you can't edit previous lines.

This is what I've come up with, but it doesn't seem to work, and I can only come up with one reason for this, but it appears to be more than just one reason.

```
if(commandArea.getCaretPosition() < commandArea.getText().lastIndexOf("\n")){
        commandArea.setCaretPosition(commandArea.getText().lastIndexOf("\n"));
}
```

This block of code lives inside this method:

```
private void commandAreaKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)
```

Comment: I recommend easier solution - command line history can be non-editable JTextArea, while current command can be editable JTextArea/JTextField. Worked well for me in my project - advanced calculator with history. That is, unless you need one line editable next no, 3rd yes etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @peenut . I did work with this solution using a JTextField to enter commands and the JTextArea to show the output, but I wanted to change that, but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DocumentFilter for JTextArea's Document. Runnable working example that allows editing last line only in JTextArea:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter.FilterBypass;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("text area test");
        JPanel panelContent = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setContentPane(panelContent);
        UIManager.getDefaults().put("TextArea.font", UIManager.getFont("TextField.font")); //let text area respect DPI
        panelContent.add(createSpecialTextArea(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //center screen
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JTextArea createSpecialTextArea() {
        final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("first line\nsecond line\nthird line");
        ((AbstractDocument)textArea.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {

            private boolean allowChange(int offset) {
                try {
                int offsetLastLine = textArea.getLineCount() == 0 ? 0 : textArea.getLineStartOffset(textArea.getLineCount() - 1);
                return offset >= offsetLastLine;
                } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex); //should never happen anyway
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {
                if (allowChange(offset)) {
                    super.remove(fb, offset, length);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
                if (allowChange(offset)) {
                    super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
                if (allowChange(offset)) {
                    super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
                }
            }



        });
        return textArea;
    }
}
```

How does it work? JTextArea is a text control, actual data has Document. Document allows listening for changes (DocumentListener), and some documents allow to set DocumentFilter to forbid changes. Both PlainDocument and DefaultStyledDocument extend from AbstractDocument, which allows setting a filter.

Be sure to read java doc:

- [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html)
- [AbstractDocument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/AbstractDocument.html)
- [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html)

I recommend also tutorials:

- [How to use text area](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)
- [How to Write a Document Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)
- [Implementing a Document Filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)

Comment: Where did you learn that? Can you link me to the book or the tutorials online, if it was there...

Comment: Added links to online official Java documentation, explaining what I know and used to solve the problem.

Comment: (1+) for the `DocumentFilter`, You can also check out [Protected Text Component](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/21/protected-text-component/) for a solution that allows multiple areas of the Document to be individually protected.